Правильное использование @typedef
Описание
У тех, кто вместо TypeScript использует JavaScript + JSDoc, нередко случаются проблемы с определением типов. К примеру interface из TypeScript можно реализовать на JSDoc вот так:

TypeScipt

interface Type {
    property1: number;
    property2: number;
}


JSDoc

/**
 * @typedef {object} Type
 * @property {number} property1
 * @property {number} property2
 */

Проблемы начинаются с наследований. И больших таких два:
Простое наследование.
Самое обычное наследование должно реализоваться с помощью каких-то дополнительных типов и костылей:

TypeScript

interface Base {
    baseProperty: number;
}

interface Derived extends Base {
    derivedProperty: number;
}


JSDoc

/**
 * @typedef {object} Base
 * @property {number} baseProperty
 */

/**
 * @typedef {object} DerivedExtension
 * @property {number} derivedProperty
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Base & DerivedExtension} Derived
 */

Наследование без изменений
Так же компилятор психует, если наследовать тип и не менять ничего в нем:

TypeScript

interface Base {
    property: number;
}

interface Derived extends Base { }


JSDoc

/**
 * @typedef {object} Base
 * @property {number} baseProperty
 */

/**
 * Этот вариант приведет к ошибке
 * @typedef {object} DerivedExtension // Получаем any
 * 
 * @typedef {Base & DerivedExtension} Derived // А тут Base & any = any
 */

/**
 * А вот это уже 
 * @typedef {{ }} DerivedExtension // Типа пустой объект
 * 
 * @typedef {Base & DerivedExtension} Derived // А тут Base & { } = Base
 */

Хотя и второй вариант не лучший, так как вообще не показывает, что есть наследование:

Дополнительно
Я понимаю, что это не совсем наследование, но так как теги @extends или @implements не работают, у меня не остается выбора.
Вопрос
Можно как-то исправить эти костыли?
Может быть, вы знаете методы использования @typedef которые работают получше?

/**
 * @typedef {{
 *  baseProperty: number;
 * }} Base
 *
 * @typedef {Base & {
 *  derivedProperty: number;
 * }} Derived
 */


Ну так берите и наследуйте...
/**
 * @typedef {object} Base
 * @property {number} baseProperty
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Base} DerivedExtension
 * @property {number} derivedProperty
 */

Чем вам такое не подходит?


Наследование без ничего
/**
 * @typedef {Base} DerivedExtension
 */


Ну, как бы это так не работает. То, что под DerivedExtension не наследуется.

@eccs0103 У меня работает(добавил картинку) Может как то не так указывается тип самой переменной?

Это было бы идеально, если бы заработало. Но у меня берет либо параметры снизу, либо то, что в скобках (object исключение). Кажется не только у меня эта проблема.

@eccs0103 Возможно проблема в самой IDE? У меня idea и она прекрасно все подсвечивает. Как варианты с наследованием, так и с объединением

Я делал это на Visual Studio Code, а сейчас проверил и на Visual Studio: тот же результат. Может там настроить можно это как-то? Я в настройках прокопался, ничего такого не нашел.

@eccs0103 Ни того ни другого нет... Возможно есть для них плагины. однако, на мой взгляд, очевидно, что проблема не в jsdoc, а в IDE, которая используется вместе с jsdoc.

Может это как-то обновить можно? Я TypeScript sdk установил и JSDoc вместе с ним установилось. Я просто привык к ним очень, не думаю только из-за такого IDE менять.
